# Make key a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a current hash:

```
{
 "2018-03-12"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-12", :net_revenue=>0.044}], 
 "2018-03-11"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-11", :net_revenue=>0.033}],
 "2018-03-10"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-10", :net_revenue=>298.860}]
}
```

How do I make it look like this?

```
{
 "2018-03-12"=>{:date=>"2018-03-12", :net_revenue=>0.044}, 
 "2018-03-11"=>{:date=>"2018-03-11", :net_revenue=>206.008},
 "2018-03-10"=>{:date=>"2018-03-10", :net_revenue=>298.860}
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the initial hash? Share your piece of code.

Comment: @Vishal, `hash = {"2018-03-12"=>0.044, "2018-03-11"=>3.039, "2018-03-10"=>0.860, "2018-03-09"=>0.029}
new = hash.map { |k, v| { date: k, net_revenue: v } }.group_by {|k, _v| k[:date]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as

```
hash.transform_values(&:first)
```

(ruby 2.4 and later)

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {
 "2018-03-12"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-12", :net_revenue=>0.044}], 
 "2018-03-11"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-11", :net_revenue=>0.033}],
 "2018-03-10"=>[{:date=>"2018-03-10", :net_revenue=>298.860}]
}
new_hash = hash.each { |k, v| hash[k] = v[0] }
```

The **new_hash** will look like:

```
new_hash = {
 "2018-03-12"=>{:date=>"2018-03-12", :net_revenue=>0.044}, 
 "2018-03-11"=>{:date=>"2018-03-11", :net_revenue=>0.033},
 "2018-03-10"=>{:date=>"2018-03-10", :net_revenue=>298.860}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than making sure the data comes in the way you want it,

```
hash.each do |key, val|
  hash[key] = val.first
end
```